# Asp.net forms authentication support for IE9

Tags: asp.net

My site is running on iis6 in window server 2003.I've used forms authentication here in my site .This is working on ie8 browser but not on ie9.it always redirect me on login page , i am already logged in.

Comment: Have you got cookies enabled in IE9?